# Check if mysql field contains a certain number in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having a table with a column that has few ids that were put into database with multi select. Column for example contains: 1,4,5,7,9. Is it possible to check if this column contains for example number 5 or not in it through MySQL query ?. 
I need to select all the people that have number 5 or some other listed in that field and print them through php.

Comment: It's definitely possible. You can do it with a LIKE statement; though it would be easier for you if your database design was normalised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
SELECT ...
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5, list_column)
```

But understand that this search is bound to be very slow.  It cannot use an index, and it will cause a full table-scan (reading every row in the table).  As the table grows, the query will become unusably slow.

Please read my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

---

You can use @MikeChristensen's answer to be more standard.  Another trick with standard SQL is this:

```
select * from TableName
where ',' || ids || ',' LIKE '%,5,%'
```

(in standard SQL, `||` is the string concatenation operator, but in MySQL, you have to `SET SQL_MODE=PIPES_AS_CONCAT` or `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI` to get that behavior.)

Another MySQL-specific solution is to use a special word-boundary regular expression, which will match either the comma punctuation or beginning/end of string:

```
select * from TableName
where ids RLIKE '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]'
```

None of these solutions scale well; they all cause table-scans.  Sorry I understand you cannot change the database design, but if your project next requires to make the query faster, you can tell them it's not possible without redesigning the table.

Comment: i know about normal forms :) and i know that this is bad. But the system is already created by someone else and i can't change it. Belive me i would make database normal if i could :D. Thanks this function is good :). I would accept this answer in 10 minutes :)

Comment: `+1` for the built-in `mySql` function..  I'll leave my answer up since it's more *standard*..

Comment: Super answer and worked perfectly. Voted. Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps:

```
select * from TableName
where ids = '5'     -- only 5
or ids like '5,%'   -- begins with 5
or ids like '%,5'   -- ends with 5
or ids like '%,5,%' -- 5 in the middle somewhere
```

It probably won't be very fast on large amounts of data.  I'd suggest normalizing these multi-selection values into a new table, where each selection is a single row with a link to `TableName`.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from your_table where concat(',',target_column,',') like '%,5,%'
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also pick up 15?

Comment: select * from your_table where concat(',',target_column,',') like '%,5,%'  ??

Comment: Now that's crafty - ensure that you've got a comma at either end, so you just need a single LIKE statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the sql query like this, for example you are looking for the number 5
select * from your_table_name where ids='5'
if you want to check the result with php just tell me i will write it for you :)

Comment: That will work if it's the only entry in the field; if the field is '1,5,9', it won't find it.

Comment: yeah, :( sorry my english is abd now i understood the question well if the filed for example contain 1,5,9,10,3 and you want to check if the field contain 10 just write select * from your_table where ids like '%5%';

Comment: Ah, not quite - that would wrongly return people with the value 15.